# Links in excel stop working when file is saved

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I was emailed an excel file with a number of links to install direct printer queues. If I open the excel attachment directly from the email the links work, but if I save the attachment to my desktop the links no longer work and I get an error “Cannot open the specified file”.

If I copy the link into Windows explorer, it works fine. Is there a way to ensure the links still work from excel when the file is saved in a shared location so anyone with access to the file can click on the links without having to copy the link into Windows explorer?

Comment: Are you saving the file with the same file type as it came to you in the email? .csv for example will not save additional information in your spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi yeah it came through as .xlsx and saving it as the same

Comment: Try removing the "update links on save" option following these steps: https://excelribbon.tips.net/T013403_Hyperlinks_No_Longer_Work_in_a_Workbook.html